# Array and if-else statement issue

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have two forms, if `$_POST['submit']` of the first form is click the second form is loaded and an array is assigned with $POST data of first form , else if the `$_POST['submit']` of the second form is pressed  the same array needs to have additional elements this time from $POST of second form, but the problem is that my array is getting empty as soon as the `elseif` is executed. I tried passing the array by reference but that did not help me.

```
 if(isset(btn_Of_Form1)) {
     echo "form2"; $my_arr =$_POST;
 }
 elseif(btn_of_Form2){
     $my_arr =array_merge($my_arr,$_POST);
 }
```

Comment: ... Are you sure that your code looks like that?

Comment: no, I its two forms between if else statement, but code is long so I did not pasted it.

Comment: I ask that because your variables don't have dollar signs.

Comment: i am sorry, i was only giving example:
if(isset($btn_Of_Form1)) 
{
     echo $form2; $my_arr =$_POST;
 }
 elseif($btn_of_Form2){
     $my_arr =array_merge($my_arr,$_POST);
 }
my problem is I am unable to hold the values of first forms $_POST in an array as soon as $_POST second submit is implement, the array only has values of second $_POST array which is quite obvious but is there any work around.

Comment: on every post you lose your previous post. workaround is to save it in $_SESSION varable and merge it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_SESSION` and `serialize`:

```
session_start();

if(isset(btn_Of_Form1))
{
    echo "form2";
    $_SESSION['data'] = serialize($_POST);
}
elseif(btn_of_Form2)
{
    $my_arr = unserialize($_SESSION['data']);
    $my_arr = array_merge($my_arr,$_POST);
}
```

Comment: @user916625: If this is the best answer you should click the checkmark.